# EF 7 MANY-TO-MANY QUERY - two query criteria

Tags: entity-framework

Please how can I write this as one EF command? It is selection from many-to-many table...

Here is EF query :

```
List<Branch> model = await _context.Branch.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.TenantUserBranch.Any(y => y.TenantUserId == Id))
     //.Where(a => a.Deleted == false)   This here throwing error                  
      .Include(b => b.AddressBranch)
       .Include(c => c.BusinessInfoBranch)
        .Include(d => d.TenantUserBranch)
         .OrderByDescending(u => u.UpdatedTime)
          .ToListAsync();


return model.Where(a => a.Deleted == false);  //Here a.Deleted... working..
```

UPDATE 1 - My simplified Entities:

```
public class TenantUser : IdentityUser<Guid> 
{
    public TenantUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Is soft deleted")]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TenantUserBranch> TenantUserBranch { get; set; } 
}

public class Branch : BaseEntityModel
{
    public Branch()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();                    
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<TenantUserBranch> TenantUserBranch { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressBranch AddressBranch { get; set; }         

}


public class TenantUserBranch : BaseEntityModel  //Many to many join table
{
    public TenantUserBranch()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }        

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid TenantUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual TenantUser TenantUser { get; set; }       

    public Guid BranchId { get; set; }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

I need load all Branches for specific TenantUser base on TenantUserId and with deleted == false (I use soft delete). TenantUserBranch is custom join table for many to many between Branch and TenantUser.

Comment: it is not clear what you want write your entities plz.

Comment: it is not working ? not filtering, throwing error?

Comment: Yes, .Where(a => a.Deleted == false) throw error...